# TableView in a Prototype CellView doesn't react

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

i have a problem... don't get why..

i have a storyboard with only one UIViewController which has a UITableView ( Outlet ). The UITableView has a Prototype Cell ( Outlet ) with his Custom Class. 
This Custom class/this Prototype Cell has a UITableView ( Outlet ) BUT this last tableView doesnt appear, doesnt react doesnt do anything ... don't get why, the links in the IB are OK...

here is my project : 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ouq6syndy489xgy/c5QbMsLDi7

this is the code which control the UITableView which doesnt react :

```
#import "Cell.h"

@implementation Cell
@synthesize tableViewForCell;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
        [self.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"hours"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"hours"];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 30;
    //return  CGSizeMake(rect.size.width/X, rect.size.height/5);
}
```

Comment: Have you set the delegate / datasource of the Tableview which is inside your cell ?

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded your project and checked. I can not simply give an answer to your question. You are doing it all wrong. You have a tableview with a prototype cell, and inside this prototypecell you have added another tableview , which is not a cell.

If you need to customize your tableview's cells, follow this tutorial,

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Hope this helps.

Comment: don't get ur 'doing it all wrong' why cannot i add a tableview to a cell.. hmm i guess i'm doing it right contrary of what u are saying